# Prisma generated model types don't mention optional parameters AT ALL

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm using Prisma for a new app, with the CockroachDB datasource.

```
❯ npx prisma version                                                              ⏎
Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 5.3.1
@prisma/client          : 5.3.1
Current platform        : darwin-arm64
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine 61e140623197a131c2a6189271ffee05a7aa9a59 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli 61e140623197a131c2a6189271ffee05a7aa9a59 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/schema-engine-darwin-arm64)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.3.1-2.61e140623197a131c2a6189271ffee05a7aa9a59
Default Engines Hash    : 61e140623197a131c2a6189271ffee05a7aa9a59
Studio                  : 0.494.0
```

I have a schema defined in prisma.schema, like this:

```
model Movie {
  id                    Int         @id
  title                 String
  releaseYear           Int
  letterboxdUri         String
  letterboxdShortCode   String
  watches               Watch[]
  backdropPath          String?
  budget                Int?
  genres                String[]
  imdbId                Int?
  overview              String?
  posterPath            String?
  releaseDate           Int?
  runtime               Int?
  languages             String[]
  status                String?
  tagline               String?
  cast                  CastRole[]
  crew                  CrewRole[]
  castSynced            Boolean     @default(false)
  crewSynced            Boolean     @default(false)
}
```

In a JS file, I'm trying to create a new Movie record. I've tried doing:

```
import { Movie } from "prisma/client";

// later

const movies: Movie[] = [];
```

and also

```
import { Prisma } from "prisma/client";

// later
const movies: Prisma.MovieCreateInput[] = [];
```

In both cases (and a number of other tries), I get an error with each optional field defined in the model schema.

```
      movies.push({
        id: tmdbId,
        title: watch["Name"],
        releaseYear: watch["Year"],
        letterboxdUri: watch["Letterboxd URI"],
        letterboxdShortCode: watch["Letterboxd URI"].split('/').pop()!,
        backdropPath: movie.backdrop_path,
        
        // ^ TS error here!
        // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'backdropPath' does not exist in type 'MovieCreateInput'.ts(2345)
      });
```

This happens for every single field marked with the `?` modifier in prisma.schema. I can't set these fields at all because the generated type doesn't mark them as optional, it just omits them entirely.

I can't figure out why this would be happening. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hey Rhodes, have you tried doing an `npx prisma generate` to regenerate the typescript types for Prisma?

Comment: OMG hey Aydrian! Great to hear from you! 

I've done that now and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this works:

```
const movies: Prisma.MovieCreateArgs["data"][] = [];
```

I'm not sure if this is the best/right way to do this, because it seems odd and not very ergonomic to have to dig into the "data" key of this type.

Comment: I think you were on the right track initially, you need to import it as a type. Looks like you weren't originally importing from @prisma/client. The @ was missing.

import type { Movie } from "@prisma/client";
const movies: Movie[] = [];

Answer (score 0):

`Prisma.MovieCreateInput` is basically the paramter type of the function `prisma.movie.create(opts)`, which you typically invoke like:

```
prisma.movie.create({ data: { title: 'Jaws', ... } })
```

You aren't really meant to use that type directly.

If you want an array of `Movie` records, then you just want the `Movie` type exported by the generated prisma client:

```
import { Movie } from '@prisma/client';
const movies: Movie[] = []
movies.push({
  //...
});
```